# How to read connection string from .net core application which runs set of Nunit test cases

Tags: .net-core, nunit

I have an appsettings.json file with the keys. I need to pass this to Nunit tests file.
how to do this?

```
{  
    "Mailing": {  
        "Smtp": {  
            "mailTo": "xxx@aperture-control.com", 
            "mailTo": "xxx",  
            "mailSubject": "Data Validation Report",  
            "mailBody": "Location Results",
            "smtpHost": "xxx",  
            "smtpPort": "xx",  
            "smtpUser": "xx@aperture-control.com",
            "smtpPassword": "xx",
        }  
    },  
    "ElasticSettings": {  
        "ClusterUrl": "xxxx",  
        "jobIndex": "uklocation",
        "host_versions": "uk"
    }  
}  
``
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the name of the file to NUnit as a run parameter.

If you are running with NUnit3-console, use the `--testparam` option to pass the name of the file. See https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/running-tests/Console-Command-Line.html

If you are using the NUnit3 Visual Studio adapter, you will need to place the argument in a `.runsettings` file. In this  case, each named parameter you wish to pass should be included as a parameter under `RunSettings/TestRunParameters/Parameter`

Within your test code, you access the value of the parameter using `TestContext.TestParameters`. One simple approach is to use `TestContext.TestParameters["myparamname"] but other options are shown in the docs at https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/TestContext.html

I haven't told you **where** in your code to place this, since you haven't indicated exactly how you want to use the information. Since you will need to parse the file, you'll want to put it somewhere where it is only executed once, or a few times. Since the parameter is static, you can save extracted values in a singleton if you like.

UPDATE

The sample test you have shown (in a comment!) gives no extra info about how you are using the test case source. It's unclear whether  only one test or many use it and whether variations are needed for different tests. So I'm giving an example that will work for the single test you have shown.

```
IEnumerable<TestCaseData> MyJSONData()
{
    string file = TestContext.TestParameters["mySettingsFile"];

    // Read your file and set name, query1 and query2
    // Use whatever software you normally use to read it

    yield return new TestCaseData(name, query1, query2);
}

[TestCaseSource(nameof(MyJSONData))]
public void MyTestCase(string name, string query1, string query2)
{
    // Put your test code here
}
```

Running under `nunit3-console.exe` you would specify the option

```
--testParameter "mySettingsFile=PATH TO YOUR FILE"
```

---

You'll have better results with future questions if you provide a full example of code rather than trying to describe it in words.

Comment: `code` 
[Test, TestCaseSource(nameof(ESComparitiveTestData))]
public void ESDataComparison(string TestCaseName, string QueryString1, string QueryString2)
{
    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("clusterURL")).DefaultIndex("locationindex");

    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

    var result1 = client.Count<location>(
        q => q.Query(r => r
       .QueryString(s => s
       .Query(QueryString1)
       )
        )
        );

}
``
Hi @charlie, Above is the code where clusterURL and locationindex needs to read as configuration keys. Give me an example

Comment: You should edit your question rather than putting complicated stuff - especially code - in a comment. Comments on SO are considered transitory and are routinely deleted. All the useful info should be in the questions and the answers. Also, it's courteous to give info to those helping you in an easy to read form - not possible in comments. I'll update my answer.